# ways to increase close to user hologram stability with Microsoft Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

Using Unity and Hololens, are there any best practices/ techniques for increasing stability of a hologram? My scenario is placing holograms (arrows) above specific small points of interest on a large object. The user needs to be relatively close to the arrows and object they’re drawing their attention to (within 1ft in some cases). Currently, when placing the arrows and moving around them, they may drift several inches horizontally or vertically, which is too much for their purpose.

I’ve been going over online tutorials and community posts and running out of options, as none have worked well enough or I’m not sure I’m implementing them correctly. 
Attempts to stabilize near user holograms:
-   Parent all the game objects (arrows) to a single holder object and creating a new anchor at said parent.
-   manually setting the stabilization plane to the arrow closest to the center of focus (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/hologram-stability#stabilization-plane and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/case-study-using-the-stabilization-plane-to-reduce-holographic-turbulence). As well as trying the same with the parent of the grouped arrow. I’m not sure if I’m envoking the stabilization plain correctly or not though (is it something called every update() cycle, or just called once when the plain location should change?)
-   I’ve skimmed over the content of a performance thread found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/performance-and-xaml-ui to make sure my scene and objects are optimized, but my content is fiarly straight forward.
-   I’ve attempted to use Vuforia for image tracking for stabilization. If you know of any other tools for using image tracking in conjunction with hololens SLAM, could you please let me know as well?

Any help or direction you could provide would be appreciated. Thanks!